# Como capturar y guardar foto en un movil con asp .net core 3.1 mvc

Tags: c#, aplicación-web, responsive, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-mvc

Tengo mi aplicación web responsive desarrollada con `asp .net core 3.1 mvc c#` y el cliente pide que desde el navegador en su móvil la aplicación pueda tomar una foto y guardarla en el móvil, visualizar con vista previa y guardar en el servidor. Tengo un código que al tomar la foto desde el browser de mi aplicación me regresa a la vista anterior

incidents.cshtml

```
// Capturar Foto 

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var captureButton = document.getElementById('captureButton');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true
    }).then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Ocurrió un error al acceder a la cámara: " + err);
    });
    captureButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });
});
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y la pregunta cual es?

Comment: @gbianchi mi pregunta es:  ¿existe alguna forma de que pueda tomar y guardar una foto desde movil con una aplicacion web-responsive hecha con asp.net core 3-1 c#?

Comment: yo supongo que si.. pero con eso no hacemos nada...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿conoceras alguna api que pueda usar para esto? estuve implementando de varias formas el framework capacitor de ionic pero no me funciono

Comment: yo no.. y no damos recomendaciones de librerias en este sitio...

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas de subir la imagen, te daré un ejemplo con la que considero la más tradicional que es mediante un form y la imagen la subiremos como cualquier fichero dentro de un `input[type=file]`

Tendrás que tener algo como esto

```
<form asp-action="GuardarFoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" />
    <button type="submit">Subir foto</button>
</form>
```

Es importante colocar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` para subir archivos

En el controlador tenemos algo como esto

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GuardarFoto(IFormFile foto)
{
    //Aquí guardamos la imagen en una carpeta o en la BD, o lo que sea que
//quieras hacer con tu imagen
```

Y en el javascript al momento de generar la foto tenemos que cargarla en el input file

```
captureButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        let imagen = new File([blob], "fileName.png", { type: "image/png" });
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        dataTransfer.items.add(imagen);
        document.getElementById("foto").files = dataTransfer.files;
    }, 'image/png');
});
```